# Installing pycurl on OS X 10.7 Lion

Tags: python, gcc, pycurl

I'm trying to install PyCurl in my local environment which has python 2.7 and gcc-4.2 on OS X 10.7 Lion. I've tried doing this based on this answer [Error installing PyCurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403757/error-installing-pycurl):

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip install pycurl
```

Which fails because I have gcc-4.2 installed via Xcode:

```
error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

I've also tried downloading the source and building a setup.py (I modified this based on [Problem trying to install PyCurl on Mac Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784449/problem-trying-to-install-pycurl-on-mac-snow-leopard/5576013#5576013)):

```
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -pipe -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/pycurl.c
```

This results in the same error as above. I have verified that I do indeed have gcc-4.2 and that it is linked to my /usr/bin.

I'm thinking that it will work if I compile it correctly so that it knows to use gcc-4.2 when installing instead of gcc-4.0. However, I don't know how to do this and have not found something to explain passing an argument to use a particular gcc. I want to avoid overriding system defaults if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you have a 32-bit-only Python 2.7 installed on your system (possibly downloaded from python.org) which was built with `gcc-4.0` and includes a PPC universal variant.  Building C extension modules with these Pythons is very problematic with Xcode 4 installed (the default for 10.7 and optional for 10.6) because `gcc-4.0` and PPC support have both been removed.  The easiest and best long-term solution is to install a 64-bit/32-bit Python build (see [the python.org download page](http://www.python.org/download/) for current releases) or simply use the Apple-supplied Python 2.7.1 (`/usr/bin/python2.7`) in 10.7.

Comment: I thought I was using the Apple supplied install of python in Lion. When I do which python it tells me the path is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python not /usr/bin/python2.7

Comment: No, the Apple-supplied Pythons are all in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`.  Your shell path has probably been modified to put that `/Library.../2.7/bin/python` directory first.  The python.org installers do that by default.  If you want to, you can undo that by modifying the appropriate shell startup file, most likely `.bash_profile`.  Look for and compare it with `.bash_profile.pysave`.

Comment: Thanks, I modified my .bash_profile to use the built in python and was able to successfully install pycurl!